# ImageView click works on emulator, not on phone (Android)

Tags: android, click, android-imageview, onclicklistener

I have ImageView as :

```
<ImageView
                android:id="@+id/btnBack"
                android:layout_width="12dp"
                android:layout_height="18dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:focusable="true"
                android:elevation="10dp"
                android:background="@drawable/ic_arrow_back"
                android:contentDescription="@null"
                android:fontFamily="@font/roboto"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                android:textSize="15sp"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

And I have done:

```
binding.btnBack.bringToFront()
```

I have set click listener to my ImageView as :

```
binding.btnBack.setOnClickListener {
                fragmentNavigator.pop()
            }
```

Things work perfectly fine on Emulator, but while testing on a real phone, I have to tap the ImageView many times to make it work. Why is this so? What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Are u sure the button is being clicked?

I had similar problems while using small sized buttons

increase the `ImageView width` and `height`.

Android Studio suggestions are at least `48dp x 48dp`